# How can I update a contingency table based on evidence?

Tags: bayesian, categorical-data, survey, contingency-tables

I have a series of contingency tables that are my population benchmarks and survey data. Practically speaking, we know the population benchmarks are largely, but not entirely, accurate; there are some biases in data collection and modeling. We have run several surveys and collected data along the same variables as the population benchmarks. These too, practically speaking, may not be entirely accurate, due to differential response rates, and random sampling error.

Given these constraints, we believe that some approach to combining these data may yield more accurate results than either set of tables singly (population benchmarks or sample crosstabs).

What approach can I use to combine these data? Or, alternatively stated, is there some approach for updating the population tables based on the sample data? I have limited Bayesian training, but it seems that this could fit into a Bayesian framework, where the population data serve as the priors and the sample data as the evidence.